# coffee script cakefile task not finishing

Tags: node.js, selenium, coffeescript, spawn

I have the following cakefile task to run selenium tests which runs successfully and gets to the end of the tests but doesn't exit.

```
muffin = require 'muffin'
wrench = require 'wrench'
http   = require 'http'
fs     = require 'fs'
spawn  = require('child_process').spawn
exec   = require('child_process').exec

task 'selenium', 'run selenium tests', (options) ->
    sel = require './test/selenium'
    app = spawn 'node', ['app.js']
    app.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
        if /listening on port/.test data
            selenium = spawn 'selenium'
            selenium.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
                console.log 'stdout: ' + data
                if /Started.*jetty.Server/.test data
                    sel.run ->
                        app.stdin.end()
                        selenium.stdin.end()
                        console.log 'completed Selenium Tests'
```

Is there a way I can tell the task to finish? I get the 'completed Selenium Tests' logged in the console.

Comment: If you take the same code (sans the `task 'selenium'` bit) and run it in a `.coffee` rather than a `Cakefile`, you get the same behavior, right?

Comment: I have converted all this code in to vanilla javascript and outside of a cakefile running automatically and I get the same outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trevor Burnham, pointed my in the right direction. But the underlying issue was that the selenium child process i was spawning was a shell script running a java process. So basically when calling app.kill() it was killing the shell script but not the underlying java process.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the two child processes (`app` and `selenium`) is still running, the main process will keep running. Calling `stdin.end()` on them doesn't change this. What you want to do is to force them to die, with the aptly-named [kill method](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child.kill):

```
app.kill()
selenium.kill()
console.log 'completed Selenium Tests'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, even used the .end() method alongside the kill() method with no luck

Comment: As the Node docs say: "Note that while the function is called `kill`, the signal delivered to the child process may not actually kill it." Try adding `app.on 'exit', -> console.log 'app exited'` (and likewise for `selenium`) to find out which process isn't exiting.

Comment: thanks, i found that the selenium child process was being killed. my mistake was that i failed to realise that it was killing the shell script opening selenium rather than the java process itself! Thanks, you helped me get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call `process.exit()`. Though, I'm not sure what the effect is on children.